# python scrapy Two-direction crawling with a spider

Tags: python, scrapy

I am reading `learning scrapy` by Dimitrios Kouzis-Loukas. Actually I have a question of the `Two-direction crawling with a spider` part in chapter 3 page58.

The original code is like:

```
def parse(self, response):
# Get the next index URLs and yield Requests
    next_selector = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"next")]//@href')
    for url in next_selector.extract():
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url))

# Get item URLs and yield Requests
    item_selector = response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="url"]/@href')
    for url in item_selector.extract():
        yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, url), 
      callback=self.parse_item)`
```

But from my understanding, should the second loop block be included into the first one so that we can first download the index page and then download all the information pages in the first page, after that move onto the next index page?

So I just wanna know the operating order of the original code, please help!

Comment: what you want ? to merge both loops on one ?

Comment: I wanna know whether I should move the second loop into the first one ?  And it will go like that download the first index page and  download all the detailed pages of the first page and then download the second index page.

Comment: actually, I know scrapy will push all the requests into a stack, and handle them sequentially, so I'm curious about the order of handling.

Comment: Is the first loop really necessary? It seems only one page can be extracted  by that xpath.

Comment: @Wade: Yes, it can only yield one request, and it could be replaced by a single call to `.get()` (or `.extract_first()`). Regarding the order, is as @stranac says, but your code should not expect any specific request order when programming asynchronously (e.g. with Scrapy)

Answer (score 1):

You can't really merge the two loops.

The `Request` objects yielded in them have different callbacks.
The first one will be processed by the `parse` method (which seems to be parsing a listing of multiple items), and the second by the `parse_item` method (probably parsing the details of a single item).

As for the order of scraping, scrapy (by default) uses a LIFO queue, which means the last request created will be processed first.
However, due to the asynchronous nature of scrapy, it's impossible to say what the exact order will be.